# Riemannian submersion that preserves the Levi-Civita connection where the fibers are not totally geodesic submanifolds?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am not an expert in Riemannian geometry. I have been told that if $f: (M,g) \rightarrow (N,h)$ is a Riemannian submersion, then if the fibers of $f$ are totally geodesic submanifolds of $(M,g)$, then $f$ preserves the Levi-Civita connection, but that the converse does not hold. So does anybody have an example of a Riemannian submersion that does preserve the Levi-Civita connection but doesn't have totally geodesic fibers?

Comment: For $M$  take the Euclidean plane in the polar coordinates (or rather an open subset where they are true coordinates), so the metric is $dr^2+r^2\,d\phi^2$, and let $f:M\to\mathbb R$ be given by $f(r,\phi)=r$.

Comment: @user8268 You should write that up as an answer.